# How to undo mocked require in jest?

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I am mocking a library by doing this:

```
let helperFn;
let mock;

beforeEach(() => {
  mock = jest.fn();
  require('./helperFn').default = mock;
})
```

If I do this in a test, does it mean that from now on within the whole test suite that default function of helperFn will be associated with that mock?

In the Jest documentations I see how to reset the mock, but I don't see how to remove the mock from a required function. I am concerned that from that test on, all the calls into helperFn.default will see that mock.

Answer (score 3):

### ES6 modules

Here is an ES6 example:

helperFn.js

```js
export default () => 'original';
```

code.js

```js
import helperFn from './helperFn';

export const func = () => helperFn();
```

code.test.js

```js
import * as helperFnModule from './helperFn';

import { func } from './code';

describe('helperFn mocked', () => {
  let mock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mock = jest.spyOn(helperFnModule, 'default');
    mock.mockReturnValue('mocked');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mock.mockRestore();
  });

  test('func', () => {
    expect(func()).toBe('mocked');  // Success!
  });
});

describe('helperFn not mocked', () => {
  test('func', () => {
    expect(func()).toBe('original');  // Success!
  });
});
```

**Details**

Since ES6 imports are live views of the module exports, it is easy to mock an export and then restore it afterwards.

---

### Node.js modules

Here is a Node.js example:

helperFn.js

```js
exports.default = () => 'original';
```

code.js

```js
const helperFn = require('./helperFn').default;

exports.func = () => helperFn();
```

code.test.js

```js
describe('helperFn mocked', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const helperFnModule = require('./helperFn');
    helperFnModule.default = jest.fn(() => 'mocked');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  test('func', () => {
    const { func } = require('./code');
    expect(func()).toBe('mocked');  // Success!
  });
});

describe('helperFn not mocked', () => {
  test('func', () => {
    const { func } = require('./code');
    expect(func()).toBe('original');  // Success!
  });
});
```

**Details**

The `default` export gets remembered by `code.js` when it runs, so changing the `default` export of `helperFn.js` doesn't affect `func` once `code.js` is `required`.  `Jest` also caches modules and returns the same module for multiple `require` calls unless `jest.resetModules` is called.

So for Node.js modules it is often easiest to `require` code within the test itself and use `jest.resetModules` to reset any mocking.